# rails getting related objects through associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, relation

Ok here's another convoluted question.

I have Show.  It has many Episodes.  A Show can have many Channels (ie Categories).

I have an episode.  I can do episode.show.channels in order to get the channels to which the episode's show belongs to.  Very clean.

Here's the kicker: I'd like to get a random x number of episodes whose shows ALSO belong to the same channels as the current episode.

Answer (score 0):

Just my two cents, but wouldn't it be easier to have your models organized like this -

```
Channel (Category or Genre)
  has_many :shows

Show 
  belongs_to :channel
  has_many :episodes

Episode
  belongs_to :show
```

Think about how you'd look up something in a TV Guide - first the Genre (Sci-Fi, Action, Horror, etc) which has a set of shows, and from that list of shows you pick one, which then has many episodes to choose from.

This would also make your logic a *lot* easier - To get the shows in a given channel, use something like this:

```
@channel = Channel.find_by_whatever
@shows = @channel.shows
```

and to get a random x number of episodes within the same channel

```
@random_episodes = []
@shows.each { |s| @random_episodes << s.episodes.sample(x) }
```

The number of episodes you're choosing isn't random (3 episodes from each show is probably not a bad starting place) - but the episodes that are chosen are picked at random - so if you reload the page you'll see different episodes each time.

Comment: What you've described is actually the way I set it up - perhaps I explained it wrong - but I do have habtm for shows and channels - because one show could be on multiple channels, and one show could have many shows.  I'll try what you've fleshed out; it was late didn't think about tossing them into an interim array to pluck from.

Comment: Also woke up thinking if I do has_many :channels, :through => :show then I can just get each episode's channels and do a quick lookup of shows without traveling up the chain but shouldn't make a difference.